# what is the > probability that only one letter will be put into the envelope with > its correct address?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Tanya prepared 4 different letters to 4 different addresses. For each
>   letter, she prepared one envelope with its correct address. If the 4
>   letters are to be put into the four envelopes at random, what is the
>   probability that only one letter will be put into the envelope with
>   its correct address?

I have solved in this way:

The way of assigning in is = 4! = 24

If we think only one assigning will be correct then we can assign this in $$ * \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 =6 \ \ ways $$
then the probability would be 6/24    =  1/4.

But the answer is given that, 1/3.

Comment: Why would one correct assigning have $6$ ways? What is the reasoning behind the formula $*\cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us count the number of ways that letter A can be in its correct envelope, which we also call A, while none of the others is in a correct envelope.

So B must go to C or  D ($2$ choices).

If B goes to C, then C cannot go to B, else D would have to go to D.  So C must go to D, and the fate of D is determined. So there is only $1$ way that B can go to C.

The same is true if B goes to D. So overall there are $2$ choices where A is the "fixed point."

That gives a total of $8$ possibilities. Divide by $4!$.

**Remark:** We could also solve this in a much more general way. We have $n$ letters, and want to find the probability that exactly $k$ of them end up in the correct envelope. The $n$ letters can be permuted in $n!$ ways. As in the answer above, that will be the denominator.

For the numerator, the lucky letters that end up in the right envelope can be chosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. The unlucky $n-k$ letters can be all put into wrong envelopes in $D(n,k)$ ways, where $D(n,k)$ is the *derangement* number. For more about counting [Derangements,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) please see Wikipedia. It uses the notation $!w$ for the number of derangements of $w$ objects.

Comment: Let we have assigned   the correct   first. If the position is fised then, we have 3  letters and 3 envelopes left. Because  we must insert the  a letter into the right envelope, I just counted the combination  of the  3  letters can assign into the 3 envelopes. So the way is $3 \times 2\ times 1$.  Where is my error  here ?

Comment: There are $4$ ways to choose the letter that goes into its proper envelope. We must put the other letters into wrong envelopes. For each of the $4$ ways to choose the letter that goes to the right envelope, there are $2$  ways to mess up all the rest. The number of ways to put $3$ letters into *right* envelopes is indeed $3!$. but that is not directly useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you put the first letter in the right envelope (4th letter / 4th envelope). What is the probability for that ?

What is the probability, that the next letter is not put in the right envelope ? It is 2/3, because there are two possible envelopes, which are wrong for a certain letter. (2nd letter / 3rd envelope).

Remaining letters: 1,4; remaining envelopes: 1,2

The probabiltity, that the next two letter are put in a wrong envelope is 1/2.

For the probability, that only letter **4** and envelope **4** matches you just multiply the probabilities.
**Edit**: bold printed

But there are also 3 equal cases: 1-1,2-2,3-3 (only matching). So you have to multiply the result with 4.